# creating a setup.exe qt

Tags: qt, installation, qt-creator

Till now I developed simple application using qt creator which run directly from qt creator, I did not create any setup.exe files to install those applications. I do not even know what the setup.exe file is. My question is, when I am done with the project i.e. .cpp, .ui, and .h files are coded then how to create a setup.exe file, so that the application can be installed on a platform? I am using windows 7.

1. Explain what is the setup.exe?
2. How to create a setup.exe?
3. What actually happens, when a setup.exe runs?
4. If the size of project files is 5KB for instance and it #includes some modules from Qt, will the size of the application increase after installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. When you select the **release version**,
2. an exe is formed in your **build folder->release folder**, copy that exe somewhere,
3. **click on it**, It will tell you what **necessary dll's file it requires**,
4. **copy it one after another** i.e copy the dll, then again click on it and so on... Search the dll's in where your qt is installed. Copy them where is your exe is.
5. And if you are loading some external images, or files... don't forget to give the path relative to the exe by using **QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath()**, in windows it gives path relative to exe. But it behaves differently in mac. Using **resource file** i.e .qrc may also help. Just load all the resources in a resource file.
6. **Now when your exe is able to work independently in itself**. Then comes the setup.exe, this is nothing but an exe, which copies all these files into a specified path. You can even write you setup.exe to do this.
7. There must be **many third party application** which will make **all the dll's** and your **files** and **your exe** into a **setup.exe.**
8. Or a simple thing would be, **make all your dlls, exe and external files into a zip**. This is your simplest setup.

Last thing, setup size depends on your exe, the dll's it requires and external files. If you use many external files then size would increase. The libraries you are using i.e if you are using network, xml module etc. then it requires more the dll's, hence increase in size of the setup.

Comment: I just loved the way you explained the steps :)
+1 for first 5 steps

Comment: I copied all the dlls to the release folder (where the .exe file lives) and run the .exe, it pops up with a message, "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information"

Comment: I additionally had to copy `libEGL.dll` to the directory where my exe file was located. Otherwise nothing happened after a doubleclick on the exe.

Answer (score 3):

To Question 1: 'setup.exe' basically copy your executable and any necessary files (include images, dlls, etc) to target machines, and setup environment for proper execution of your program (e.g. dll registration)

To Question 2: You have to write your own deployment tools for Qt applications.

- Either you write a script to copy your compiled programs, and any necessary libraries to target machine. Check documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html), and [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/16732)
- Or use 3rd-party tools to generate your 'setup.exe' for you, like [NSIS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/)

To Question 3: see above

To Question 4: To my understanding, the size of a dynamically-linked Qt application mainly depends on your 'core' program, as other Qt modules are readily compiled.

Comment: You should add to your question that there is no Windows design guidelines that state that an installer must be called `setup.exe`, in fact most of the time they are not.  Also there is now a Qt installer framework in beta available: https://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-Installer-Framework